# Excel custom formatting: just time to be red in datetime format

Tags: excel, datetime, custom-formatting

I want to specify custom formatting in Excel :
datetime:

```
rrrr-mm-dd gg:mm
```

and I would like gg:mm to be red, is that even possible?

Cause when I do:

```
rrrr-mm-dd gg:mm [Red]
```

the label red goes in front and the whole datetime format is red.

```
[Red]rrrr-mm-dd gg:mm
```

Thanks!

Comment: Excel cannot do that with formatting.  You will either have to split the date and time into two cells, as suggested by Gary's Student; or use a VBA macro to either convert the cell to just a text string (or place a text string in an adjacent cell for display, and then differentially format using a VBA routine.

Answer (score 1):

I would cheat!

In **A1** and **B1** enter:

```
=NOW()
```

Format **A1** as *"yyyy-mm-dd"* and format **B1** as *"hh:mm"*.  Then align **A1** to the right and align **B1** to the left.  Then set the background colour of both **A1** and **B1** to *White*.  Finally format the **B1** font to be *Red*:

[image]

I see no problem with using two cells.  After all, cells are cheap.